# Concentrated Yerba Mate

Tags: tea, camping, mate

I love yerba mate, I drink A LOT, and I would like to bring some with me backpacking.  Do you think I might save a few ounces to carry if I brewed my mate beforehand, concentrated it into a thick goo and then took that with me backpacking?

How would I do that? Just simmer it for a few days? That seems like not the best idea...

Also, is there any online retailer where I can find such a product for purchase?

Answer (score 4):

**You could do that, but it would not save much weight and will be perishable.**  The concentrate will have enough water to spoil.  If you want to take this course still, prepare a concentrate by using about 4x as much mate and steeping somewhat longer.  You can reduce it over low heat, but probably not enough to get a sludge without hurting the flavor.

If you're concerned about weight, I suggest light equipment. 50g of mate will make you about 15+ cups of it.  To steep it, I suggest getting a very light tea infuser, either a basic basket or cup with built-in infuser. This way you can enjoy fresh yerba mate.

Answer (score 4):

I have a feeling that you're going to be much better off with loose leaf tea here. Teavana claims that their mate tea is good for [25-30 t/2ozs](http://www.teavana.com/the-teas/mate-teas/p/toasted-yerba-mate-tea) or ~15 cups. Considering that you can brew it 2-3 times, you can get 30-45 cups of tea from 2oz of dry tea.

Condensing a Mate into a syrup you'd need to be able to concentrate it to the point of 1 oz making 45 cups of tea in order to get even an ounce of weight savings. That means that you'd have to condense ~300oz of liquid tea into a single ounce.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative exists: simply buying ready-made **instant yerba mate**. It looks like this:

[image: Instant Yerba Mate powder, photo by Yerbamarket.pl]

As you can probably see, it's a fine powder, a teaspoon's worth is about equivalent to a fresh gourd fill - so, it's quite efficient for when you're on the go.

Do note that:

- the powder is indeed fine and *very* sticky, so you have to take care when preparing your brew (e.g. when backpacking, shield yourself from the wind). Otherwise, it might get *everywhere*.
- the taste is somewhat different from "real" yerba mate (I would say not as good, but passable).
- the powdered form contains a quite substantial amount of caffeine per teaspoon (about comparable to a typical energy drink can). While nearly not as dangerous as pure, powdered caffeine, you should still be mindful of the dosage.

As a bonus, after you're done backpacking, a small amount blends surprisingly well with vodka *(but recall the caffeine dosage note above)*!